# How to log messages in Robot Framework Java?

Tags: java, logging, robotframework

I use Robot-Framework 3.0 on top of Jython 2.7.0.

In Robot-Framework-Python, you can perform logging like below,

```
from robot.api import logger

def sample():
    logger.info("A sample message")
```

But, I am not sure how to do the same in Java? I tried searching online, but I couldn't find any articles related to it.

I also tried logging through Apache Logger like below -

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Sample{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Sample.class);

    @RobotKeyword("Print Message")
    @ArgumentNames({"message"})
    public void printMessage(String message){
        logger.info("I'm inside");
    }
}
```

But, I coudn't find where the message is ending up.

Please let me know how would you perform logging for your Java-Robot-Framework libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are down-voting please let me know the reason

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your log4j configuration. The simplest approach is to use a ConsoleAppender. The gotcha there is you have to tell log4j not to use saved references to System.out/err. See [Robot Framework: log messages sent through log4j's ConsoleAppender are not visible in output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19095403/2532697).